# Why is psfrag not substituting my text for a .eps graphic?

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, psfrag

I am currently writing a document that contains a number of .eps files. Unfortunately it also contains a number of PNGs too. What i have done to get around the Latex/pdfLatex problem is to have two documents. Document 1 is the main document and contains all my text, writing, images etc. Document 1 contains only PNGs and is compiled in pdfLatex.
Document 2 is essentially an art collection, where I import the .eps files and replace the text in the .eps file with text in a maths style font. I generate the pdf of document and screenshot the images into a PNG that then eventually gets put into document 1. Now this works fine, or did until
psfrag just stopped working. No errors in  compilation, nothing, it just doesn't substitute the text.

Original image:

[image]

Substituted image:

[image]

So, as you can see, it used to work but now it just outputs the original image with no changes at all.

And how this image is called in latex:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \psfrag{DC}{$V_1$}
    \psfrag{SW1}{$SW_1$}
    \psfrag{i(t)}{$i(t)$}
    \psfrag{v(t)}{$v(t)$}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{simple_switch_pulse.eps}
\end{figure}
\pagebreak
```

My TexStudio setup:

[image]

Build settings:

[image]

And finally the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{psfrag}

%\usepackage{scicite}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{pythontex} 
%\usepackage{minted}
%\usepackage{pdftex}
\usepackage[siunitx, americanvoltages,oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]     %removes chapter headings eg. Chapter 1
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\large}
\topmargin -2.54cm
%\oddsidemargin 0.2cm
\textwidth 15cm 
\textheight 23cm
\begin{document}
```

So what could the issue be? I have no errors, I don't know what could have changed to prevent this from functioning correctly.

As requested, a portion of the eps. It's definitely text (as it's worked previously).

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Title: simple_switch_pulse.eps
%%Creator: XCircuit v3.4 rev10
%%CreationDate: Sun Jul 09 16:15:13 2023
%%Pages: 1
%%BoundingBox: 68 68 271 155
%%DocumentNeededResources: font Times-Roman font Symbol 
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
%
%  PostScript prolog for output from xcircuit
%  Version: 3.3
%
%  Electrical circuit (and otherwise general) drawing program
%
%  Written by Tim Edwards 8/5/93--7/13/05  (tim.edwards@multigig.com)
%  The Johns Hopkins University (1993-2004)
%  MultiGiG, Inc. (2004-present)
%
%%BeginResource: procset XCIRCproc 3.3 0
%
% supporting definitions --- these are the primary xcircuit types.

/XCIRCsave save def
/topmat matrix currentmatrix def

/fontslant { /slant exch def [1 0 slant 1 0 0] 
    exch findfont exch makefont dup length dict /ndict exch def
    { 1 index /FID ne { ndict 3 1 roll put } { pop pop } ifelse } forall
    ndict definefont pop} def
/ul { dup type /stringtype eq showflag 1 eq and { gsave 
   currentpoint topmat setmatrix 0 0 moveto 2 index stringwidth pop (_)
   false charpath flattenpath pathbbox grestore exch pop 1 index
   sub setlinewidth exch pop currentpoint 3 -1 roll add moveto 0
   rlineto stroke moveto } if } def
/ol { dup type /stringtype eq showflag 1 eq and { gsave gsave
   currentpoint topmat setmatrix 2 index stringwidth pop 3 index
   true charpath flattenpath pathbbox grestore exch pop
   exch pop topmat setmatrix (_) true charpath pathbbox grestore
   exch pop 1 index sub setlinewidth exch pop currentpoint
   exch 4 1 roll exch sub add moveto pop 0 rlineto stroke
   moveto } if } def
/stW { gsave currentpoint newpath moveto true charpath flattenpath
    pathbbox pop exch pop sub grestore } def
/Ts {mark Tabs aload pop counttomark 1 add array astore /Tabs exch def Tabs
    0 currentpoint pop put} def
/Tbn {mark Tabs aload pop counttomark dup 2 add 1 roll cleartomark 1 sub} def
/Tb { 0 1 Tbn {Tabs exch get dup currentpoint pop lt
    {currentpoint exch pop moveto exit} {pop} ifelse } for } def
/Tf { Tbn -1 0 {Tabs exch get dup currentpoint pop gt
    {currentpoint exch pop moveto exit} {pop} ifelse } for } def
/qS { (aa) stW (a a) stW sub 4 div 0 Kn } def
/hS { qS qS } def
/pspc 0 def
/cf0 { scalefont setfont } bind def
/Kn { dup kY add /kY exch def rmoveto } bind def
/ss { /fscale fscale 0.67 mul def currentfont 0.67 cf0 0 fscale0 fscale mul
    0.33 mul neg Kn} def
/Ss { /fscale fscale 0.67 mul def currentfont 0.67 cf0 0 fscale0 fscale mul
    0.67 mul Kn } def
/ns { 0 kY neg Kn /kY 0 def /fscale 1.0 def xfont0 1.0 cf0 } def
/CR { ns 0 /Bline Bline fscale0 neg add def Bline moveto } def
/cf { dup type /realtype ne {1.0} if exch findfont exch kY 0 eq
    { 40 mul dup /fscale0 exch def cf0 /xfont0 currentfont def}
    {fscale0 mul fscale mul cf0} ifelse } def
/ctmk { counttomark dup 2 add -1 roll pop } bind def
/label { gsave translate 0 0 moveto dup scale neg /rotval exch def
    /just exch def just 384 and 0 gt {/mshow {pop} def} {/mshow {show}
    def} ifelse just 16 and 0 gt {gsave rotval rotate 0 1 dtransform
    gsave pagemat setmatrix idtransform exch grestore 1 0 dtransform
    gsave pagemat setmatrix idtransform exch grestore dup abs 1e-9 lt
    {pop mul 0 gt} {3 1 roll pop pop 0 lt} ifelse grestore {-1 /rotval
    rotval neg def /just just dup 3 and 1 ne {3 xor} if def} {1} ifelse
    exch -1e-9 lt {-1 /rotval rotval neg def /just just dup 12 and
    4 ne {12 xor} if def} {1} ifelse scale } if /showflag 0 def
    /fspc pspc def /Bline 0 def /Tabs 0 array def /fscale 1.0 def
    /kY 0 def gsave dup 1 add copy 0 exch 1 0 dtransform exch atan rotate
    {exch dup type /stringtype eq {true charpath flattenpath} {dup type
    /arraytype eq {exec} {12 string cvs true charpath flattenpath} ifelse}
    ifelse} repeat pop pathbbox grestore 3 -1 roll pop 3 1 roll just
    1 and 0 gt {just 2 and 0 gt {exch pop neg fspc sub} {exch sub 0.5
    mul neg} ifelse} {pop neg fspc add} ifelse exch Bline exch just 4
    and 0 gt {just 8 and 0 gt {exch pop neg fspc sub} {add 0.5 mul neg}
    ifelse} {pop neg fspc add} ifelse rotval rotate Kn currentpoint
    translate /showflag 1 def /Bline 0 def /Tabs 0 array def /fscale
    1.0 def /kY 0 def {dup type /stringtype eq {mshow} {dup type
    /arraytype eq {exec} {12 string cvs mshow} ifelse} ifelse} repeat
    grestore } def
/pinlabel { 4 index 32 and 0 ne hlevel 0 eq or { /pspc 10 def label
    /pspc 0 def } { pop pop pop pop pop {pop} repeat } ifelse } def
/pinglobal { pinlabel } def
/infolabel { pinlabel } def
/graphic { gsave 4 index cvx exec /DataSource get resetfile translate
    0 0 moveto neg rotate dup scale cvx exec image grestore } def

/scb { setrgbcolor } bind def  /sce { defColor aload pop scb } bind def
/cRedef {/defColor currentcolor 3 array astore def} def
/begingate {dup type /dicttype ne {1 dict} if begin % default params
    dup type /dicttype ne {1 dict} if begin     % instanced params
    /hlevel hlevel 1 add def /defColor currentcolor sce 3 array
    astore def gsave sce translate 0 0 moveto neg rotate dup abs scale
    } bind def
/endgate { /hlevel hlevel 1 sub def grestore defColor aload pop cRedef
    scb end end} bind def

/hlevel 0 def
/tmpa [1 0 0 1 0 0] def
/gar {8 8 true tmpa {<c0 c0 00 00 0c 0c 00 00>} imagemask} bind
{8 8 true tmpa {<30 70 60 02 03 07 06 20>} imagemask} bind
{8 8 true tmpa {<0c 1e 1e 0c c0 e1 e1 c0>} imagemask} bind
{8 8 true tmpa {<0f 0f 0f 0f f0 f0 f0 f0>} imagemask} bind
{8 8 true tmpa {<3f f3 e1 e1 f3 3f 1e 1e>} imagemask} bind
{8 8 true tmpa {<df cf 8f 9f fd fc f8 f9>} imagemask} bind
{8 8 true tmpa {<ff 3f 3f ff ff f3 f3 ff>} imagemask} bind 7 array astore def
/ppaint { gsave clip tmpa dup setmatrix pathbbox neg exch neg 4 2 roll
  neg 4 -1 roll 2 copy gt {exch} if 8 div ceiling 8 mul 4 2 roll neg 2 copy
  gt {exch} if 8 div ceiling 8 mul 3 -1 roll -8 5 -1 roll
  { 3 index exch 5 exch put dup -8 3 index { 3 index
  exch 4 exch put 3 index exec } for } for pop pop pop pop grestore } bind def
/setstyles {
  currentlinewidth mul setlinewidth /style exch def
  style 1 and 0 gt not {closepath} if
  style 2 and 0 gt {currentlinewidth 4 mul dup 2 array astore 0 setdash} if
  style 4 and 0 gt {0.5 currentlinewidth 4 mul 2 array astore 0 setdash} if
  gsave style 16 and 0 gt { style 224 and -5 bitshift style 256 and 0 gt {
  7 exch sub 8 div dup 1 exch sub currentrgbcolor 3 array astore
  {3 copy mul add 4 1 roll pop} forall pop pop setrgbcolor eofill}
  {dup 7 lt {gar exch get ppaint} {pop eofill} ifelse} ifelse}
  {style 256 and 0 gt {1 setgray eofill} if} ifelse grestore style 8 and 0 gt 
  style 512 eq or {newpath} {stroke} ifelse grestore} def     

/polygon { gsave /num exch def moveto num 1 sub {lineto} repeat setstyles } def
/xcarc   { gsave newpath arc setstyles } def
/elb { matrix currentmatrix 7 -1 roll 7 -1 roll translate 5 1 roll 4 -1 roll
    3 index div 1 scale } def
/ele { 0 4 1 roll 0 4 1 roll } bind def
/ellipse { gsave elb newpath ele arc setmatrix setstyles } def
/pellip  { elb ele arc setmatrix } def
/nellip  { elb ele arcn setmatrix } def
/spline  { gsave moveto curveto setstyles } def
/polyc   { {lineto} repeat } bind def
/beginpath { gsave moveto } bind def
/endpath { setstyles } bind def
/bop     { 1 setlinecap 0 setlinejoin 6 setmiterlimit 0 0 0 scb cRedef } def
/psinsertion {/PSobj save def /showpage {} def /setpagedevice {pop} def bop
    rotate translate dup scale} def
/end_insert {PSobj restore} def
/setpagemat {/pagemat matrix currentmatrix def} def
/inchscale  {setpagemat 0.375 mul dup scale} def
/cmscale    {setpagemat 0.35433071 mul dup scale} def

%%EndResource
%%EndProlog

% XCircuit output starts here.

%%BeginSetup

/source {
% hidden
begingate
1 1.00 0 0 32 0.00 360.00 xcarc
1 1.00 0 32 0 64 2 polygon
1 1.00 0 -32 0 -64 2 polygon
endgate
} def

/vsource {
begingate
1.00 0 0 0 source
(+) {/Symbol cf} 2 5 0 1.00 0 18 label
(-) {/Symbol cf} 2 5 0 1.00 0 -18 label
1.000 0.000 0.000 scb
(v.p) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 9 0 1.00 0 64 pinlabel
(v.m) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 13 0 1.00 0 -64 pinlabel
endgate
} def

/inductor {
begingate
1 1.00 20 -28 20 -44 0 -48 0 -24 spline
1 1.00 -20 -20 -20 -32 0 -28 0 -24 spline
1 1.00 20 32 20 16 0 12 0 36 spline
1 1.00 20 12 20 -4 0 -8 0 16 spline
1 1.00 20 -8 20 -24 0 -28 0 -4 spline
1 1.00 -20 20 -20 8 0 12 0 16 spline
1 1.00 -20 0 -20 -12 0 -8 0 -4 spline
1 1.00 0 -48 0 -64 2 polygon
1 1.00 0 36 0 48 2 polygon
1.000 0.000 0.000 scb
(l.1) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 9 0 1.00 0 48 pinlabel
(l.2) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 13 0 1.00 0 -64 pinlabel
0.180 0.545 0.341 scb
(spice:L%i %pl.1 %pl.2 1.0U) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 0 0 1.00 -208 -160 infolabel
(sim:l %pl.1 %pl.2) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 0 0 1.00 -208 -208 infolabel
endgate
} def

/circle {
% trivial
begingate
1 1.00 16 0 6 0.00 360.00 xcarc
1 1.00 0 0 10 0 2 polygon
1.000 0.000 0.000 scb
(out) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 4 0 1.00 16 0 pinlabel
(out) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 7 0 1.00 0 0 pinlabel
endgate
} def

/arrowhead {
% trivial
begingate
8 -28 beginpath
3 -18 3 -15 0 0 curveto
-3 -15 -3 -18 -8 -28 curveto
-2 -26 2 -26 8 -28 curveto
249 1.00 endpath
endgate
} def

/switch {
% trivial
begingate
1 1.30 32 32 2 -43 2 polygon
1 0.60 0 -48 57 49.00 90.00 xcarc
-1.00 90 0 -64 circle
0.60 270 -12 8 arrowhead
1.00 90 0 48 circle
1.000 0.000 0.000 scb
(sw.1) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 9 0 1.00 0 48 pinlabel
(sw.2) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 13 0 1.00 0 -64 pinlabel
endgate
} def

/arrow {
% trivial
begingate
1 0.80 0 -40 0 20 2 polygon
1.00 0 0 40 arrowhead
endgate
} def


%%EndSetup

%%Page: 1 1
%%PageOrientation: Portrait
/pgsave save def bop
1.0000 inchscale
2.6000 setlinewidth 624 288 translate

1.00 0 -400 0 vsource
1.00 0 -32 0 inductor
-1.00 90 -208 80 switch
1 1.00 -400 80 -400 64 2 polygon
1 1.00 -400 80 -272 80 2 polygon
1 1.00 -32 -64 -32 -80 2 polygon
1 1.00 -32 48 -32 64 2 polygon
1 1.00 -32 64 -32 80 -160 80 3 polygon
1 1.00 -32 -80 -32 -96 -400 -96 -400 -64 4 polygon
1.00 360 0 0 arrow
1.00 180 -62 -6 arrow
(DC) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 16 0 1.00 -352 -16 label
(SW1) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 16 0 1.00 -256 32 label
(i\(t\)) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 16 0 1.00 -128 0 label
(v\(t\)) {/Times-Roman cf} 2 16 0 1.00 32 0 label
pgsave restore showpage

%%Trailer
XCIRCsave restore
%%EOF
```

Comment: Can we see the EPS? The strings inside the EPS matters, it might be that it doesn't actually say SW1 in the EPS. Or the contents of the EPS might be an image...

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: a screenshot doesn't help. You need to show the actual eps-file.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I misunderstood what was being asked. It's not an issue with the eps file.

Comment: to test what psfrag is doing we need the eps-file.

Comment: Should i post the whole thing? It's over 200 lines long...

Comment: Work just fine for me, but you haven;t fully explained how you process the file. I use `latex` + `dvips` (this is where the psfrag happens) + `ps2pdf`. It seems to substitute just fine.

Comment: take the eps you posted and put it in an empty folder. Add a tex file with the preamble `\documentclass[12pt]{report}\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{psfrag}\usepackage{times}`  and your figure code. Compile with latex + dvips + ps2pdf. If it doesn't work, make a zip of the whole folder and put it somewhere for inspection.

Comment: @daleif what further information would be useful? I'm a novice with Latex. What's confusing me is why it has stopped working when it was fine before.

Comment: You only show here that you are using latex and ends up with a pdf. But we have no information as to what exactly you do to get from dvi to pdf or that you're actually using latex and not pdflatex (which does not support psfrag). Instead of relying on build in your editor, explicitly run, latex, dvips ps2pdf. That is what Ulrike and I did and it works just fine. You need to be 100% sure what exactly hour tool chain is doing here for this to work. (note that I know at least two ways from dvi to pdf and only one of the supports psfrag, thus the chain matters)

Comment: Hi, this is becoming not worth it. I think I'll just use overleaf as that's working.